# How can I upload local changed files to an FTP server?

Tags: linux, ftp, upload

I use a PHP IDE that has no built-in ability to upload a project to a site.

So, I'm looking for common easy to use tool for Linux that would able to upload modified documents to the server instead of uploading of the whole site.

I also  accept shell scripts that would be able to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [`lftp`](http://lftp.yar.ru/) if you don't have it yet. Then create a bash script containing the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET='/remote/folder'
SOURCE='/your/local/folder'  
lftp -f "
open <hostname>
user <username> <password>
lcd $SOURCE
mirror --reverse --delete --verbose $SOURCE $TARGET
bye
"
```

Replace `<hostname>`, `<username>` and `<password>` with your actual data.

This will effectively sync your local files to the remote folder, deleting everything that doesn't exist locally anymore (this is the `delete` option). `--reverse` specifies that you want to actually update your remote folder instead of your local one.

Have a look at `lftp`'s [man page](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) for more details. And *always* have a backup ready so you don't delete anything in case a command goes wrong.

<sub>This is adapted from [this script here](http://sina.salek.ws/content/how-mirrorsync-remote-ftp-folder-local-folder).</sub>